# Sending HTML e-mail

Tags: html, email, drupal, drupal-6, subscription

i'm using Drupal 6. How can I create HTML e-mails for subscriptions (i.e via a template)? `mail_edit()` offers plaintext messages: can I use it for sending HTML mail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to look at the [HTML Mail](http://drupal.org/project/htmlmail) module, which provides templating support for e-mails.